# Why does unfreezing a track in Ableton change the tracks sound?

Tags: software, daw, ableton-live

I'm using Massive synth inside Ableton and I need to freeze tracks to save on the CPU usage. The problem is that when I unfreeze the synth tracks the sound of the synth is different from when I originally froze the track. The sound hasn't completely changed.. it's still the same sound but slightly different, like some of the parameters have been tweaked??

Answer (score 4):

It's because when you unfreeze a track in ableton, the phases of the oscillators change.
If you want the oscillators to always be the same, you have to go to the OSC section, and then click "Restart via Gate". Doing so will make sure that the oscillators have the same phase every time you play a note.

Answer (score 2):

I think there's some parameters in your Massive preset that are modulated randomly.
When you freeze a track you actually render it to audio, so everything is printed and fixed.
...